# Base64 encoding in C# - Issue while sending an attachemnt via REST POST method

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, base64

Is it possible in C#/Xamarin to encode byte array to Base64 like it's possible in Java?! 
`byte[] encBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buffer);`

So I'm **not** looking to turn bytes in **Base64 string** I'm looking for **byte array** encoded with Base64, as is done in Java

Edit to reflect answer:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fileLen];
int offset = 0;int numRead = 0;
while ( offset < buffer.length && ( numRead = input.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length - offset)) >= 0) 
{
 offset += numRead;
}
byte[] encBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buffer);
```

So, a buffer is populated with data from a file and then encoded to base64.

I don't see a way to read a file from a source, like in that snipet.

Edit2:

The issue, it seems, is not just the encoding but sending the encoded file to the server. 

When sending a file, it creates a file on the server but file is either corrupted (pdf and excel) or blank (docx).

Answer (score 1):

like this in java

```
public static String toBase64(String value){
byte[] message = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
}
```

in C#

```
 byte[] array = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
 string base64 =Convert.FromBase64String(array);
```

Comment: But with this I'm, again, getting Base64 String, and not a byte.